# How does "boxing" work in .NET?

Tags: .net

I know what "boxing" is:

```
object myBox = 5;
```

Now I wish to increase my knowledge. Is a special type created for this boxing operation? Or is `System.Object` used? How does .NET handle boxing?

Comment: see msdn on [boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Comment: MSDN has all information you need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: is all about implementition.. i was not thought to look inside the MSDN

Comment: WHY VOTE CLOSED !?? please help me what is wrong with question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no special type; a boxed value type is an implementation detail of the runtime. But the easiest way to understand it is to imagine that there is a special type:

```
class Box<T> where T : struct
{
    T value;
}
```

Where the type `Box<T>` also implements all the methods, interfaces, and so on, of T, for whatever T happens to be. So, for example, you could imagine that `Box<int>` has a method ToString which simply calls int.ToString on the value, and returns the result.

Boxing is simply a mechanism for getting a reference to something that is not of reference type. You just make a box around the thing and get a reference to the box.

Answer (score 2):

The CLR handles boxing.

Consider what happens in this case:

```
private void myUselessMethod()
{
     int i = 5;
     object o = i;
}
```

`'i'` is a valueType (an Int32) and, as a local variable, is allocated on the stack ,it allocates only 4 bytes, presumably.
Then, `i` is wrapped into an object i.e. boxed.
What the CLR (Common Language Runtime) does:

- It allocates memory on the managed heap: Namely, enough space for an Int32, plus the space for two additional overhead members which every object on the managed heap must have -- the 'type object pointer' and the 'sync index'.
- It copies the value 5 into the newly allocated heap memory.
- It returns the address of the memory in the heap as the reference o.

What I find most confusing about this boxing/unboxing/reference type/value type business is that on one hand, everything is an object, even value types are objects and derive from `System.Object`. On the other hand, when an Object is declared, it is always a reference type.

So

```
void myMethod(System.Object o)
{
    doStuff();
}

void myCallingMethod()
{
    int i = 5;
    myMethod(i);
}
```

will box i to pass it to myMethod, even though `i` is an int, a valueType, and as such perfectly well an object, since value types are derived from `System.Object`, too.

Answer (score 0):

As `Bala R` mentioned...

there is no better example than the one provided by MSDN

> [Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)