# "Storing" value types inside an ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

The `ArrayList` class can only contain references to objects but what happens when you store a value type such as integers?

```
string str = "Hello";
int i = 50;

ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList();

arraylist.Add(str); // Makes perfectly sense: 
                    // Reference to string-object (instance) "Hello" is added to 
                    // index number 0

arraylist.Add(i);   // What happens here? How can a reference point to a value 
                    // type? Is the value type automatically converted to an 
                    // object and thereafter added to the ArrayList?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "boxing" work in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997398/how-does-boxing-work-in-net)

Comment: Not really - you'd only know the two are related if you already knew the answer to this question.

Comment: @Binary worrier - It's the same subject, but then you need to know how it's called ..

Comment: @mavnn that doesn't mean they aren't the same thing, though ;p A little duplication (especially with different titles etc) is healthy, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called "boxing": automagically the int is converted to a reference type. This does cost some performance.

See also [Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you pull up the `ArrayList` class in ILSpy, you'll see that the backing store is:

```
private object[] _items;
```

and that the `Add` method accepts an instance of type `object`:

```
public virtual int Add(object value) { ... }
```

So when you call `Add` with an integer, .NET [boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) the integer and then it gets added to the `_items` array in the `ArrayList` as an `object`.

Incidentally, if you need an `ArrayList` of just integers and you are using the .NET 2.0 Framework or later, you should use the [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (a.k.a. generic List) class instead, which will perform better since it avoids having to box an `int` when storing or retrieving it from the list (see the Performance Considerations section in that last link).

Answer (score 1):

Its called boxing. A "Box" holds a copy of the struct along with details of what type it is.

MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

In framework 2.0 + microsoft gave us generics which are faster and more effictive:

MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [Arraylist.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add.aspx) will adds take any value and adds as an object, so the integer value will be automatically converted(boxing) and is added in to arraylist.